# how to make a copy of response of http.Get(url) request in Golang

Tags: go, net-http

I'm trying to use `resp, err := http.Get(url)` command to write the response to file as well as use the same response to extract links.

After I write the content to a file using `resp.Write(f)`, I cannot use `resp.Body` for another purpose (for the response from the above url) without making another `http.Get` request.

I tried `resp2 := bytes.NewBuffer(resp)`. It gives eror as type does not match. I've tried copy as well.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: You can't read the response body once you've already drained it. Have you tried using [ReadResponse](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ReadResponse) on the buffered response?

Comment: [code here](https://play.golang.org/p/Aj8KKfQGfD) This produces new file with header info and no body on `resp.write(f)`. BTW, thanks @JimB on earlier question. Can you provide example on ReadResponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the response fits in memory, just create a buffer and use [resp.Write](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Write), like (untested, basically correct):

```
var b bytes.Buffer
if err := resp.Write(b); err != nil {
   // handle error
} else {
    // Do something with buffer
}
```

for code that works with any reader, use: [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll), which returns a new  []byte containing the data that you can then wrap in a bytes.Buffer

Comment: You might want to pass a reference to the buffer, like `resp.Write(&b)`, to avoid a `Cannot use 'b' (type bytes.Buffer) as type io.Writer` error.

Answer (score 3):

httputil has a response dump. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest
It will replace the body with an in-memory copy so you can reuse it.